# Keylistener not running

Tags: java

This is my code, I have a key listener however it does do what it is supposed to do when the key is pressed.  The shape moves as it should in the ActionListener however when I press one of the keys it does nothing.

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

    import javax.swing.*;


    public class Snake extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
        double x = 0 , y = 0, xVel = 2, yVel = 2;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40);
            g2.fill(circle);
            t.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if(x < 0 || x >460)
            {
                xVel = -xVel;
            }

            if(y < 0 || y > 459)
            {
                yVel = -yVel;
            }
            x += xVel;
            y += yVel;
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  //This part of the Code Doesnt seem to be running
        {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if( key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            {
                yVel = yVel; //There may be something wrong with the way i wrote this
                xVel = 0;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                yVel = -yVel;
                xVel = 0;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                xVel = xVel;
                yVel = 0;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                xVel = -xVel;
                yVel =0;
            }
            x+= xVel;
            y+= yVel;
            repaint();

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you haven't implemented the `KeyListener` interface.  You're going to want to add that to your `implements ActionListener, KeyListener` and then register the the class for the KeyListener as well as implement the methods provided by the `KeyListener` interface.

For more information on `KeyListener` look at [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a similar project, how I do it:

1) Implement KeyListener (can't recall if that is the exact name*)

2) addKeylistener(this)

3) Write the method which you have already done.

*Might be KeyboardListener

Answer (score 0):

You need to .addKeyListener to your frame.  So where ever you created your frame you need to add this:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                if( key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                {
                    yVel = 2;
                    xVel = 0;
                }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                {
                    yVel = -2;
                    xVel = 0;
                }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                {
                    xVel = 2;
                    yVel = 0;
                }
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                {
                    xVel = -2;
                    yVel =0;
                }
                x+= xVel;
                y+= yVel;
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {    
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        frame.add(snake);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```